# Matrix of density estimates with np package R

Tags: r, kernel-density

I am trying to understand the np package in R.

In particular, if I run this code with the classical package kde I get

```
# Simulated data from a bivariate normal
library(ks)
n <- 200
set.seed(35233)
x <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n = n, mean = c(0, 0),
                      sigma = rbind(c(1.5, 0.25), c(0.25, 0.5)))

# Compute kde for a diagonal bandwidth matrix (trivially positive definite)
H <- diag(c(1.25, 0.75))
kde <- ks::kde(x = x, H = H)
```

From which I can obtain, from kde$estimate, a matrix of the density estimates.

If now I try with

```
fhat <- npudens(x)
summary(fhat)
```

I get the fhat$dens is a vector.

How can I get a matrix too?

And also, can somebody help me in plotting this density?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `plot(fhat)` plots a 2d density.